# Keep absolute element inside view port horizontally

Tags: jquery, css

I've an absolute positioned tooltip element that pops up when clicked. However, under certain conditions this element can go too far right and add a horizontal scrolling to the page. My idea is to always keep it inside the view port horizontally.

Much like if you're using Windows and right click anywhere on the screen a menu pops out. It's usually shown on the bottom right side of the mouse cursor, however if this action is done on the bottom right of the screen, the menu comes up on the top left part of the cursor.

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cEqz6/1/

HTML

```
<div class="view-port">
    <div class="div-holder">
        <div class="absolute-div">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.view-port {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: auto;
}
.div-holder {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dadada;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
    left: 500px
}
.absolute-div {
    position: absolute;
    background: #333;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

.absolute-div, must always be inside .view-port

Comment: Do you show the tooltip using Javascript? Do you calculate the position using Javascript? If so: why not just avoiding that condition by making the proper calulcations? If the tool tip has a hardcoded position using `right: 0` for the `absolute` positioned element might help (IMO it won't hurt for screens with enough space on the right).

Comment: This actually does help. Since my tooltips are poping up at the bottom right corner of posts, positioning them with right: 0 and adding a maximum width equal to the post width (so they won't go too far on the left) is quite a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you know the position of where the tooltip should appear (usually the mouse position). From there, you can add the tooltip's width, and see if it falls off the right side of the viewport.

If this is the case, you can then apply some CSS, maybe add a "tooltip-right" class, which causes the tooltip to appear on the other side of the target position.

A similar principle can be applied if the tooltip would appear too far down, falling off the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: That's a really good idea and could have worked, however @try-catch-finally gave me a nice alternative and since my code is already filled up with javascript it's a bit of a relieve to not use JS for this fix. Thank you anyway!